# python-shell not working in emacs

Tags: python, emacs

I am trying to configure emacs for python development. I have installed the following packages from melpa - python-mode ipython.

I would like to interactively develop, have the code file open in one frame and the python shell open in another, and have the ability to reload the changes in my code file in the shell.

As per the article - http://pedrokroger.net/2010/07/configuring-emacs-as-a-python-ide-2/, I should be able to load my code in the shell using C-c ! or M-x python-shell. However on executing either of this nothing happens !

I have not downloaded the python-mode.el manually, but installed the packages from repos, is that creating a problem ?

I would appreciate help in resolving this issue

Comment: I used the same link only for setting up emacs in ubuntu and  it worked fine for me.

Comment: Did u install python-mode from the repo or manually downloaded the python-mode.el file ?

Comment: Instead of python-mode, you might try the new python.el at https://github.com/fgallina/python.el . It seems more recent than the older two alternatives and will be in the next emacs release IIUC. It has instructions for configuring with IPython, though I haven't tried it myself yet.

Comment: Which emacs version? I thought that any recent emacs version comes with `python-mode` built-in. It may only be `ipython` that is lacking. Try de-installing the packages and see if you can still run `M-x python-shell`.

Comment: @Evert I uninstalled it and the plain python shell shows up now.

Comment: @JonO yes it has https://github.com/fgallina/python.el/issues/16, however can I install the mode using package.el ?

Answer (score 1):

It was resolved by installing python and ipython packages and then adding the config mentioned in the python.el file to init.el.